# Why does my CSS Scroll Snap not show multiple HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am making a page that scrolls though different images when you scroll horizontally (with CSS Snap Points to make the scroll stick to images). The page has four columns, and each column has a different height.  With two images in the first column, and the other columns will only have one image.

While I was testing this out, I added another image and some text to the first column (now the first column has two images and a `p` element with the value of "hello!"). But when I went to that page, I noticed that only the last image shows - covering up the `p` element nd the first image - kind of like I have set the `position` rule to `absolute`, but I checked my CSS and I don't have any `position` rules.

Why is only my last image showing up, and not both them??

---

Here's the code I'm working with:

```css
.website {
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: auto;
 -webkit-white-space: nowrap;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 0;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 -webkit-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
 scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

#pictures {
 height: 100%;
}

.page {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link href="http://www.jeffarries.com/tests/scroll.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body>
<div class="website" id="pictures">
 <div class="page">
  <p>hello!</p>
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/2.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/2.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/3.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="page">
  <img class="page" src="http://treehouse-codepen.s3.amazonaws.com/snap-points/4.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `font-size:0;` is what is killing your `p`; `.page` clamps to `width:100%;`, so your `img:nth-of-type(2)` is currently living in the overflow space of `div.page:first-child`, which is behind `div.page:nth-child(2)`. There a reason you need those wrapping `div.page`s to be `width:100%;`?

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for responding and I apologize for the delay of my response.  The `width:100%;` makes the `.page` be 100% of `.website`, which is 100% of the screen.  If remove the `width:100%;` from `.page`, I get this: http://www.jeffarries.com/tests/test, and as you can see the text shows, but the second image still does not.  Why is `div.page;first-child` behind `img:nth-of-type(2)`, and how can I fix that? (It may be something obvious, I don't know all the ins and outs of HTML and CSS)

Comment: Because `overflow` is defaulted to `visible` on its containing div, and said containing div is `width:100%`, meaning it's cutting off its child. The `div`s on your test page are still set to `width:100%`

Comment: Oooops!  I removed (really did this time) the `width:100%;` from `.page`. Are you saying I should remove the `width:100%;` from `.website` as well?

Comment: @abluejelly Removing the `width:100%;` from `.website` makes the image show up, but it's to the right of the first column, instead of below it.